# Export data to existing EXCEL file from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\contact.xls;', 
'SELECT * FROM [$Sheet1]') 
select * from Persons
```

This code not working..It is giving the error

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned 
message "The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object '$Sheet1'.  
Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path 
name correctly.".
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" 
for linked server "(null)".
```

Please help

Comment: If i remove the '$' then also giving the same error..Please help anyone

Comment: then what should I write please tell me

Comment: Added an answer. Try "[Sheet1$]".

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that `The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object '$Sheet1'`, and so you should `Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly`.

Comment: No I have checked the object and sheet name

Comment: Is there a sheet called $Sheet1?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Excel sheet names]

Identify the name of the sheet you are trying to "connect" to. Have a look at the picture above. The standard sheets are called "Sheet1" to "Sheet3". Your workbook under `D:\contact.xls` probably has custom names. Use the name you find there and add a `$` to the end of it.

```
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
```

Comment: Hi cularis..how will I find the custom names?can u please elaborate

Comment: There is even a picture in my answer! Just open contact.xls with excel and look at the buttom left corner.

Comment: Did you try putting the dollar at the end of Sheet1 and removing it from the front?

Comment: insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\contact.xls;', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
    select * from Persons

Comment: Michelle: Click Start, Run.  Enter `d:\contact.xls`, press Enter.  Confirm there is a sheet called exactly `Sheet1`.  Try the code above.  Verify that the error message says EXACTLY the same as in your original question?  As a developer you'll learn quickly that 'still not working' is THE most useless piece of information you can ever possibly conceive of giving.